# 'configure_file' incorrectly expands a variable

Tags: cmake

I have the following codes in `mylib.pc.in`, and want to use the CMake command `configure_file(mylib.pc.in mylib.pc)` to generate a correct `mylib.pc` file which is expanded from `mylib.pc.in`; but this doesn't work.

```
prefix=$ENV{HOME}/xcompiled-root/
exe_prefix=${prefix}
libdir=${prefix}/lib
includedir=${prefix}/include

Name: @PROJECT_NAME@
Description: @PROJECT_DESCRIPTION@
Version: @PROJECT_VERSION@

Requires:
Libs: -L@{libdir} -lpthread -lrt -ldl  -lm
Cflags: -I@{includedir}
```

I just want the `mylib.pc` be something like this:

```
prefix=/home/myusr/xcompiled-root/
exe_prefix=/home/myusr/xcompiled-root/
libdir=/home/myusr/xcompiled-root/lib
includedir=/home/myusr/xcompiled-root/include
...
```

but I get this:

```
prefix=/home/myusr/xcompiled-root/
exe_prefix=
libdir=/lib
includedir=/include
...
```

what should I do?!

Comment: well, is prefix variable correctly set?

Comment: @KamilCuk as I mentioned the output file "mylib.pc", prefix is correctly configured, but not others

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Construction `${prefix}` is a variable reference **both** in CMake scripting **and** in `.pc` file scripting. So you need to choose at **which stage** you want to expand this reference:

1. If you want **CMake** to expand this reference, you need to have a **CMake variable** 
   named `prefix` when you use `configure_file`:

   ```
   # File: CMakeLists.txt
   set(prefix "$ENV{HOME}/xcompiled-root/")
   configure_file(mylib.pc.in mylib.pc)
   ```

   Note, that with such setting you no longer need to define `prefix` variable in `.pc` file:

   ```
   # File: mylib.pc.in
   exe_prefix=${prefix}
   libdir=${prefix}/lib
   includedir=${prefix}/include
   ```

   Resulted `mylib.pc` file will be:

   ```
   exe_prefix=/home/myusr/xcompiled-root/
   libdir=/home/myusr/xcompiled-root/lib
   includedir=/home/myusr/xcompiled-root/include
   ```
2. If you want to expand variable reference `${prefix}` only when **pkg-config** is 
   called, you need to **prevent CMake** to expand this reference. E.g. you may insert `${}` construction, which expanded by CMake to nothing, between `$` and `{` characters:

   ```
   # File: mylib.pc.in
   prefix=$ENV{HOME}/xcompiled-root/
   exe_prefix=$${}{prefix}
   libdir=$${}{prefix}/lib
   includedir=$${}{prefix}/include
   ```

   Then, with common `configure_file`

   ```
   # File: CMakeLists.txt
   configure_file(mylib.pc.in mylib.pc)
   ```

   you will have following `mylib.pc` file:

   ```
   prefix=/home/myusr/xcompiled-root/
   exe_prefix=${prefix}
   libdir=${prefix}/lib
   includedir=${prefix}/include
   ```

   When this file will be processed by `pkg-config`, `${prefix}` will be expanded (internally) to `/home/myusr/xcompiled-root/`.
3. If you do not want to bother about escaping `${}` construction, use `@ONLY` option
   for `configure_file`. With that option CMake only expands `@VAR@` but leaves
   `${var}` unchanged:

   ```
   # File: CMakeLists.txt
   # Construction @VAR@ doesn't support reference to environment variable.
   # So prepare pure CMake variable which contains $ENV{HOME}.
   set(user_home "$ENV{HOME}")
   configure_file(mylib.pc.in mylib.pc @ONLY)
   ```

   With `@ONLY` option you may simply use `$` in the `.in`:

   ```
   prefix=@user_home@/xcompiled-root/
   exe_prefix=${prefix}
   libdir=${prefix}/lib
   includedir=${prefix}/include

   Name: @PROJECT_NAME@
   Description: @PROJECT_DESCRIPTION@
   Version: @PROJECT_VERSION@

   Requires:
   Libs: -L@{libdir} -lpthread -lrt -ldl  -lm
   Cflags: -I@{includedir}
   ```

   Note, that CMake leaves unchanged `@{var}` construction too. This is because `{` character is not valid for a variable's name in CMake.

Comment: so by this answer there is no need to check mylib.pc, and it is enough just to check mylib.pc.in?!

Comment: Not sure what do you want to "check", but content of resulted `mylib.pc` is still important: exactly this file will be processed by `pkg-config`, which knows nothing about CMake and its variables. My answer just describes ways for obtain *desired* `mylib.pc` from the `mylib.pc.in` template.

Comment: thx; it seems that my knowledge about `pkg-config` is not so good, so I resolve this one as the answer